# How do remove the flickering in this ImageMagick produced animation. Ive tried exactly as documented

Tags: imagemagick, animated-gif

How do I remove the flickering in this ImageMagick produced animation. Ive tried exactly as documented.

```
magick.exe  -dispose none -delay 0  ./temp/0000.png  -dispose previous -delay 9 ./temp/$($prefixName)*  -loop 0 ./output/$($prefixName).gif
```

- The first image is an empty transparent image
- The next following images are several images for the animation
- I did exactly as documented, even with -delay 0, I can see the flicker
- IM version is 7.1.1-11, platform is Windows 11, code run in Powershell script
- There's a visible flicker of the blank image

[image: flickering animation]

Comment: It's a GIF. It looks like you've got a couple of blank frames at the beginning or end of the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flicker is your empty frame `0000.png`. There is no "instant" frame replacement in a Gif (in other words your `-delay 0` is replaced by the smallest allowed delay), so your empty image is visible for a short while.

But specifying that initial frame appears unnecessary, you can generate your animation with

```
magick.exe  -dispose previous -delay 9 ./temp/$($prefixName)*  -loop 0 ./output/$($prefixName).gif
```

and IM does the right thing with the first frame:

[image]